# Searching on pressing enter button using selenium not working with Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium

I have the below code. What I actually want to do is enter a string in text field and click on enter. Then search results should be displayed.

But here on 'element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);' application logs out. I checked with URLs. URLs should be same after searching.But it changes here.
This code works for Chrome and IE. Issue only with Firefox only.I checked the element type to confirm the clicking. It was text box only.

```
public static void pressEnterKey(WebDriver driver,WebElement element){
    System.out.println("Current URL1" + driver.getCurrentUrl());
    WebElementType elementType = WebElementHelper.findElementType(element);         
    System.out.println("Element Type = " + elementType);
    element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    System.out.println("Current URL2" + driver.getCurrentUrl());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug report regarding this issue, it seems to be specific with .NET and FireFox.

See here:
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2079

The result would be to use

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.Return);
```

Comment: No problem! Just a FYI, the Return (carriage return) key is the one on the main part of the keyboard and the enter key is attached to the number pad.

Answer (score 0):

If the sole purpose is to **click on the "Enter" button, instead of sending "Enter" keys why not click on the respective element.**

Just replace the code **`element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);`** in your code above with either of the below code(s):

```
element.click();
```

### OR

```
element.submit();
```

On another note, [as per the definition](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence...)), **sendKeys method** is used to type into an element. And, I am pretty sure you can't type into a button. :)